# How can I sort a meteor Post collection by time of insertion of last Comment

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am working on my first project using Meteor, and am having some difficulty with sorting.

I have a collection for Posts and a collection for Comments, inside the comment collection I have a postId with the Id of the post it belongs to (it works good)

I am now trying to show in the DOM all the posts and show below that "Last updated at time/hour" but I want to show the time of the last added comment within that post

This is what I have tried so far (but I am new to Meteor so might be way off)

```
Template.postList.helpers({

    lastCommented: function() {
        var post = Posts.find(this._id);
        var lastComment = Comments.find({postId: post}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
         return lastComment.createdAt();
```

Any help on how to do that?

Thank

Comment: and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Updateed with what I have tried so far but I might be way off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `findOne` instead of `find`, or use `fetch()[0]`. Also, fields in result objects are not functions. It also seems that you already have the post id, so why look it up once more?

It's hard to say without seeing your db schema, or more code, but this might be what you need:

```
Template.postList.helpers({
    lastCommented: function() {
        var lastComment = Comments.findOne({postId: this._id}, 
                                           {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
        return lastComment.createdAt;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

didn't understand the question correctly, maybe you should have posted the code. though for sorting with time you can use the collection name with date_created: -1.

this will sort in descending order as per your requirement

> Post.find({}, {sort: {date_created: -1}});

this might work

Comment: I am trying to get the date created of the last comment inside a post

Comment: I have updated my code with what I have up until now maybe you can help from there if its more clear?

Answer (score 0):

To keep it simple add a field called, `lastCommentedOn` to your `Post` schema.

Everytime a comment is added, update the timestamp of `lastCommentedOn`, now getting the posts with the latest comments is as simple as `Post.find({}, { sort: { lastCommentedOn: -1 } })`

You could look at https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks to automate the `lastCommentedOn` updation everytime a comment is added.

Comment: Haven't thought about this way and it could work also, ended up doing it as Christian Fritz and it worked